# Обнулит выбор в выпадающем списке django

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Есть чекбокс, по нажатию на него появляется выпадающий список. Человек может выбрать в нем один из вариантов.
Как сделать, чтобы после того как у чекбокса была снята галочка (человек передумал выбирать этот вариант), в выпадающем списке выбранное значение обнулялось (по умолчанию None)?
Использую django, bootstrap5

```
<label class="container" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#monday_timesheet" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="monday_timesheet" >{{ form.monday }} Понедельник<span class="checkmark" ></span></label>
    <div class="collapse" id="monday_timesheet">{{ form.monday_timesheet }}<br></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: меняйте значение через JS

Comment: Я конечно порылся в эту сторону, но у меня не вышло

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[href="#monday_timesheet"] input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    let val = $(this).value() # или val(), не помню
    if (!val) {
        $("#monday_timesheet select").value(null); # или val(null)
    }
});
```

Предоставьте отрендеренный вариант формы, чтобы пример был более полным

На всякий случай [информация о подключении JS к форме](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/media/)